# Client side validation false for minSizeLimit in IE7,8,9, on using yii EAjaxUpload extension?

Tags: yii, file-upload, yii-extensions

I am using yii EAjaxUpload extension to upload images, It works fine in other browser except IE. Client side validation of mizSizeLimit does not works as in other browser it shows message about this.
Please suggest a solution for this problem.

Comment: do we have to Guess the errors or notification messages?

Comment: In IE does not show the error message, while with client side validation it should show the message about minimum size limit.

Comment: Please check the javascript console for errors in IE. (Hit `F12` and check the `Console` tab)

Comment: Please provide an url so we can test something

Answer (score 0):

Go to the php.ini and set the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize may be to 10M. That should help.
And if not it would be better if you could provide the error message you are receiving